# Change hidden name on drag drop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to drag `<li>` elements from one `<ul>` and drop them on another `<ul>`.

The drag/drop process works.

Because I need to POST the results to another php page, I created the origin `<li>`'s as follows:

```
<li>Test<input type="hidden" name="list1[]" value="Test" /></li>
<li>OK<input type="hidden" name="list1[]" value="OK" /></li>
```

However, when I drop a `<li>` on the destination, I would like to give the destination `<li>` another hidden input name.

Current behaviour is that the dropped element inherits the exact same input name as the original element. So when I drag the first element above to it's destination, it also gets this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="list1[]" value="Test" />
```

Is there a way to change the name "list1[]" in the input statement to something else?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your code; this is too minimal. However, is there any reason you can't just use the parent `ul` element to determine which input is where? Again, need to see more code to give you an answer.

Comment: to change only attr name, you can do..  $('desired-element').attr('name', 'value'). - value will be whatever name you want to give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that something like this might be what you are looking for.

```
jQuery("li").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    jQuery(event.target).attr("name", "NAME_OF_NEW_LIST");
  }
});
```

I think I may have written a similar Riot element if you are interested in using it to solve this problem.  It moves options elements between two selectboxes but the concept should be very similar.  Here is the link: https://github.com/jfehrman/humdrum-components/blob/master/src/list_builder.tag

Comment: Thanks. This code did give me more insight. Although not quite compatible, I certainly can use it with adaptation.

Comment: user3734431, glad that it worked out.  Let me know if you run into any other issues with it and I will see what I can do to help.